# Ubuntu 18.04 console freezes when listing external usb drive directory

Tags: 18.04, usb, external-hdd

The problem appears to occur if I press tab multiple times while listing the external drive directory.  Here's an illustration of what has occurred.  In Console 1, I was trying to list the contents of a lower directory and pressed tab several times to get the listing of the next directory level.  The console froze.   If I open a new console and try to list media/john, it freezes.  If I open a third console, and use strace, the output is below.  It froze on the second strace command.  strace output has been reduced to show only several of the first and last lines.

One other thing.  This used to occur frequently, and I would do a reflash (NVidia Xavier) in order to reduce the frequency.  But I read if you change the cable to the external hard drive, that would help.  So, I have changed the cable, and switch hard drives, and added a powered (plug-in) USB 3.0 hub to connect the hard drive to.  So, this problem doesn't occur often now.  And now, I typically do a soft reboot in order to continue.

Here's details on the current problem.

Console 1

```
ls /media/john/My\ Passport/lower_dir <tab><tab><tab>  #FROZEN, NO RESPONSE
```

Console 2

```
ls /media/john/  # FROZEN NO RESPONSE
```

Console 3 (Frozen on the second strace command)

```
strace ls /media/john

execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/media/john"], 0x7ff925cb28 /* 78 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5593562000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64/atomics", 0x7ff21eb100, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64", 0x7ff21eb100, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/atomics", 0x7ff21eb100, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
SKIP OUTPUT
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3004224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3004224, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9b08a000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=37, ws_col=204, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/john", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/john", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768)   = 144
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
write(1, " JGV_1\t L4T-README  'My Passport"..., 34 JGV_1    L4T-README  'My Passport'
) = 34
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Second entry on console 3

```
john@john-desktop:/usr/share/visionworks/sources/bin/aarch64/linux/release$ strace ls /media/john/My\ Passport

execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/media/john/My Passport"], 0x7fd38aa4f8 /* 78 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5589523000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/aarch64", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tls", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/aarch64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/aarch64/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/aarch64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/aarch64", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls/aarch64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls/aarch64/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls/aarch64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls/aarch64", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tls", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/aarch64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/aarch64/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/aarch64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/aarch64", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls/aarch64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls/aarch64/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls/aarch64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls/aarch64", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/tls", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/aarch64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/aarch64/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/aarch64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/aarch64", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/atomics/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/atomics", 0x7ff1f312b0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=362639, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 362639, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f877a8000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\20\17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0644, st_size=26464, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8782a000
mmap(NULL, 91120, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f87791000
mprotect(0x7f87797000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f877a6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7f877a6000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\320c\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=134296, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 207032, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f8775e000
mprotect(0x7f8777e000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f8778d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7f8778d000
mmap(0x7f8778f000, 6328, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8778f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0`\10\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1341248, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1409880, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f87605000
mprotect(0x7f87744000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f87754000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13f000) = 0x7f87754000
mmap(0x7f8775a000, 13144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8775a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18544, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 82176, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f875f0000
mprotect(0x7f875f3000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f87603000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f87603000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\330\\\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=137872, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 177104, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f875c4000
mprotect(0x7f875db000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f875ea000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f875ea000
mmap(0x7f875ec000, 13264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f875ec000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/john/projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\360\27\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=399136, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 463008, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f87552000
mprotect(0x7f875b3000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f875c2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x60000) = 0x7f875c2000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f87828000
mprotect(0x7f87754000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f875ea000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f875c2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f87603000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f8778d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f877a6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x557fe68000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f8782e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f877a8000, 362639)            = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f87828b10)           = 13038
set_robust_list(0x7f87828b20, 24)       = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f875c9760, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f875c9828, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ff1f33070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ff1f33070)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5589523000
brk(0x5589544000)                       = 0x5589544000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 405
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/selinux/config", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3004224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3004224, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f87274000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=37, ws_col=204, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/john/My Passport", # FROZEN NO RESPONSE
```

In a fourth and fifth consoles, I tried

Console 4

```
dmesg --follow
[85291.611121] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 24)
[85453.540630] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 10)
[85525.926518] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 10)

<Entered console 5 inputs during this period>

[85814.469940] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 50)
[85984.681325] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 20)
```

Console 5

```
ls /media
>> Output: john
ls /media/john  # FROZEN
```

Not sure if the output in console 4 is related to console 5, because there was a delay before any output showed up in console 4

In response to comments

```
sudo blkid   # Note: Drive sdb that has the problem

/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="L4T-README" UUID="1234-ABCD" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="0f9fbfeb-6a30-406f-8018-433571082670" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/mmcblk0p1: UUID="74f42614-71ad-4530-a759-53c632c42347" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="APP" PARTUUID="168ec87f-aa75-4cb1-9d51-2a140cedf333"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: PARTLABEL="mts-mce" PARTUUID="5c5200b4-5962-4c1f-ac9e-081703496f69"
/dev/mmcblk0p3: PARTLABEL="mts-mce_b" PARTUUID="371cb7f7-2812-4c11-9ded-ab44a5ec9c5c"
/dev/mmcblk0p4: PARTLABEL="mts-proper" PARTUUID="59ead28b-a167-41da-9eb6-6e1a8ac23923"
/dev/mmcblk0p5: PARTLABEL="mts-proper_b" PARTUUID="68972d48-f6c0-42f3-a845-9c53006b5c6a"
/dev/mmcblk0p6: PARTLABEL="cpu-bootloader" PARTUUID="5324f8fc-d276-477e-a8c2-007dec157c31"
/dev/mmcblk0p7: PARTLABEL="cpu-bootloader_b" PARTUUID="1830379f-ac05-473e-a342-947892d30f67"
/dev/mmcblk0p8: PARTLABEL="bootloader-dtb" PARTUUID="7765f840-e3dc-4b13-89c1-3237c0c0f40d"
/dev/mmcblk0p9: PARTLABEL="bootloader-dtb_b" PARTUUID="47c58e52-12e6-4b5d-8cad-e841068f1724"
/dev/mmcblk0p10: PARTLABEL="secure-os" PARTUUID="677c6c48-4c38-48f1-8ad8-860d4024991e"
/dev/mmcblk0p11: PARTLABEL="secure-os_b" PARTUUID="6502744b-c527-4232-a510-367bd646ed3e"
/dev/mmcblk0p12: PARTLABEL="eks" PARTUUID="040d668f-c7c3-45a4-a009-2762d793a46c"
/dev/mmcblk0p13: PARTLABEL="eks_b" PARTUUID="2898be83-4e88-45c3-98fe-00577fb7bd7b"
/dev/mmcblk0p14: PARTLABEL="bpmp-fw" PARTUUID="2d4220fe-c140-4401-accd-392d9d587245"
/dev/mmcblk0p15: PARTLABEL="bpmp-fw_b" PARTUUID="4b406d45-100f-45ce-af2c-822c8665a642"
/dev/mmcblk0p16: PARTLABEL="bpmp-fw-dtb" PARTUUID="40e1f3ec-edf9-43b4-8626-9b503e82a708"
/dev/mmcblk0p17: PARTLABEL="bpmp-fw-dtb_b" PARTUUID="2f1200df-d412-4283-8411-bf2c286d8e16"
/dev/mmcblk0p18: PARTLABEL="xusb-fw" PARTUUID="6b75204b-e94e-4a45-a891-273596947750"
/dev/mmcblk0p19: PARTLABEL="xusb-fw_b" PARTUUID="0c78ae76-a24d-405d-acdb-640f05158610"
/dev/mmcblk0p20: PARTLABEL="rce-fw" PARTUUID="46026a10-e4cd-418b-9ca8-2a7d93289b6e"
/dev/mmcblk0p21: PARTLABEL="rce-fw_b" PARTUUID="274f3355-a7b4-442b-92e0-586a54549154"
/dev/mmcblk0p22: PARTLABEL="adsp-fw" PARTUUID="282d68f5-ad7e-4792-b1ac-031a3ad66d73"
/dev/mmcblk0p23: PARTLABEL="adsp-fw_b" PARTUUID="3d60bd8e-d921-4685-803b-14367ab1427e"
/dev/mmcblk0p24: PARTLABEL="sce-fw" PARTUUID="2a3ac71a-6206-46af-b833-ea06f9c74c59"
/dev/mmcblk0p25: PARTLABEL="sce-fw_b" PARTUUID="19333619-44fc-43a9-a135-db6f6456a804"
/dev/mmcblk0p26: PARTLABEL="sc7" PARTUUID="6def2e4b-c689-4502-baea-1f55c1dc677a"
/dev/mmcblk0p27: PARTLABEL="sc7_b" PARTUUID="556068d6-c666-4484-86f1-ed0ae6d2621b"
/dev/mmcblk0p28: PARTLABEL="BMP" PARTUUID="5610ab33-9aa2-4818-b9fb-fd0989de5f7d"
/dev/mmcblk0p29: PARTLABEL="BMP_b" PARTUUID="5c444257-db8c-4456-9d32-f1514cab7104"
/dev/mmcblk0p30: PARTLABEL="recovery" PARTUUID="0be9890a-dfce-4bf4-8681-df7798464a49"
/dev/mmcblk0p31: PARTLABEL="recovery-dtb" PARTUUID="327ab8ef-bd47-4df3-92f8-8c470980b55c"
/dev/mmcblk0p32: PARTLABEL="kernel-bootctrl" PARTUUID="34a31f4d-2bca-4e77-8348-02366655d64d"
/dev/mmcblk0p33: PARTLABEL="kernel-bootctrl_b" PARTUUID="022070c7-7d24-45dd-8aab-7e52129f0f70"
/dev/mmcblk0p34: PARTLABEL="kernel" PARTUUID="4ae043ae-96c4-479e-937b-776a84ac4020"
/dev/mmcblk0p35: PARTLABEL="kernel_b" PARTUUID="0c235d2b-6d99-4565-ab7f-a33b5e083462"
/dev/mmcblk0p36: PARTLABEL="kernel-dtb" PARTUUID="7d7e083b-7ae4-45a1-a7e6-935f924ac259"
/dev/mmcblk0p37: PARTLABEL="kernel-dtb_b" PARTUUID="39f85670-19c4-4185-9ef5-335e7bdfe145"
/dev/mmcblk0p38: PARTLABEL="CPUBL-CFG" PARTUUID="1d79f993-7765-4613-9326-2c0f82b2f44f"
/dev/mmcblk0p39: PARTLABEL="RP1" PARTUUID="040734ac-1e26-46b9-8c32-aa2cf953aa38"
/dev/mmcblk0p40: PARTLABEL="RP2" PARTUUID="253049f0-7a8f-42ac-a0a9-8006b7ba5027"
/dev/mmcblk0p41: PARTLABEL="RECROOTFS" PARTUUID="0889f7b3-552a-48ff-8959-6017613b6a53"
/dev/mmcblk0p42: PARTLABEL="UDA" PARTUUID="009debef-d59c-41d7-a6e7-aa731a49c10c"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="My Passport" UUID="B4D48115D480DB4E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d46b4b7e-01"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="JGV_1" UUID="872C-7496" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/zram0: UUID="3f0d06b3-efb1-405e-be77-a91f02e8e113" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram1: UUID="9e6fb89e-4e51-41f0-bdc1-505225ef77e1" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram2: UUID="1f0b61f0-282d-4477-90f7-28b3c4d3071a" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram3: UUID="60421085-017b-46fa-be3e-1872d5b3ea83" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram4: UUID="40cc6393-65d3-4d71-bec7-816a087efdd9" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram5: UUID="bd80c78c-812d-4414-bfe2-1e6765bddad2" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram6: UUID="23161a4f-ff53-45af-8a42-659d2e229fc5" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram7: UUID="970c185c-8776-4f92-b193-27395cbc57f4" TYPE="swap"
```

```
lsblk -S  # Note: Drive sdb has the problem
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
sda  2:0:0:0    disk Generic- SD Card          1.00 usb
sdb  3:0:0:0    disk WD       My Passport 0830 1065 usb
```

```
sudo fdisk -l
# Partial output
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.7 GiB, 500074283008 bytes, 976707584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd46b4b7e

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 976707583 976705536 465.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Have you tried a file system check?

Comment: I did try a file system check some time ago, like weeks ago, on the initial drive when it was occurring so frequently.  I haven't tried with the drive that I swapped with.  Can you recommend commands / link for performing a file system check.

Comment: Hmm, my response isn't showing up...  Anyway, I tried a file system check weeks back on the previous drive.  Haven't tried a file system check since swapping drives.  Can you recommend commands to enter?

Comment: 1. determine what filesystem is used on your USB drive by typing `blkid` into console. Look for the _TYPE="..."_ output. Just please post the output of command `blkid`. PS you may find your USB drive via command `lsblk -S`.

Comment: blkid <return>: doesn't have any output;;;
blkid -V:
blkid from util-linux 2.31.1  (libblkid 2.31.1, 19-Dec-2017);;;

 lsblk -S: ;;;
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
sda  2:0:0:0    disk Generic- SD Card          1.00 usb
sdb  3:0:0:0    disk WD       My Passport 0830 1065 usb

Comment: You need to use just `blkid` and not `blkid -V`. Try `/sbin/blkid`. Please post the results in your original post, formatted as code.

Comment: Extended question above (give me a minute)

Comment: Please also post the results of `lsblk -S` in your original post.

Comment: Is `sdb  3:0:0:0    disk WD       My Passport 0830 1065 usb` your mentioned USB drive in your original post?

Comment: Yes, drive sdb "My Passport" is the USB drive referred to in the original post.  I'm going to try unplugging the drive and plugging it back in, to gain access to the data on the drive.

Comment: Your drive sdb "My Passport" is formatted with the Microsoft NTFS filesystem, which is not fully supported by Linux/Ubuntu. Use Windows for a check of that filesystem. PS if you've installed Windows onto drive sdb "My Passport", never ever try to write data within Linux/Ubuntu on it, otherwise you risk fatal data loses. Only read data from that drive within Linux/Ubuntu. In Windows 10, search for program `cmd`, run it as Administrator and type `chkdsk DRIVELETTER:`, where DRIVELETTER is the letter of your drive, for example `d`; example: `chkdsk d:`. **PS FAT32 filesystem is supported by all**

Comment: PS if you've installed Windows on drive sdb "My Passport", deactivate "Fast Startup" mode in Windows.

Comment: Interesting.  It is an old windows drive.  I'm working from home, due to pandemic, and using what I have here.  I haven't picked up a new drive yet.  But, I will prioritize getting a new drive.  I clicked on the drive icon on the left panel, and that froze the system, so I had to do a soft reboot.  After reboot, I can access the drive.  Thank you for the info.  I have a deadline this afternoon, so I'll try the chkdsk later, and get a new drive formatted for linux.